# qt creator canvas and setlinewidth issue

Tags: c++, qt, canvas

I've an issue about using "canvas" with "SetLineWidth" parameter.

I guess, it is caused by creating inheritance, or it may be due to the library installations. I've already installed the qwt libraries, and have no problem with them.

I guess, it is better to write down the code here to be more specific and helpful :

```
#include <qwt/qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt/qwt_plot_marker.h>
#include <qwt/qwt_plot_curve.h>
#include <qwt/qwt_legend.h>
#include <qwt/qwt_series_data.h>
#include <qwt/qwt_plot_canvas.h>
#include <qwt/qwt_plot_panner.h>
#include <qwt/qwt_plot_magnifier.h>
#include <qwt/qwt_text.h>
#include <qwt/qwt_math.h>
#include <qwt/qwt_plot_renderer.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <qprinter.h>
#include <qprintdialog.h>
#include <QMouseEvent>

#include "plot.h"

Plot::Plot(QWidget *parent, char *titel, int bufSize, bool fixedScaleX, bool fixedScaleY,
           double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY,
           bool displayScaleX, bool displayScaleY,
           char* textScaleX, char* textScaleY) : QwtPlot(parent) {

mY = (QwtPlotMarker*) 0;
setAutoFillBackground(true);
setPalette(QPalette(QColor(165, 193, 228)));

QwtText title(titel);
title.setFont(QFont("Arial", 11));
setTitle(title);

if(fixedScaleX) {
    setAxisScale(xBottom, minX, maxX);
}

if(fixedScaleY) {
    setAxisScale(yLeft, minY, maxY);
}

if(displayScaleX) {
    enableAxis(xBottom, true);
    if(textScaleX[0] != '\0') {
        QwtText xAxis(textScaleX);
        xAxis.setFont(QFont("Arial", 11));
        setAxisTitle(xBottom, xAxis);
    }
} else {
    enableAxis(xBottom, false);
}

if(displayScaleY) {
    enableAxis(yLeft, true);
    if(textScaleY[0] != '\0') {
        QwtText yAxis(textScaleY);
        yAxis.setFont(QFont("Arial", 11));
        setAxisTitle(yLeft, yAxis);
    }
} else {
    enableAxis(yLeft, false);
}

// canvas
canvas()->setLineWidth(3); // Problem is here
canvas()->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box | QFrame::Plain);//Problem is here
canvas()->setBorderRadius(15);//Problem is here

QPalette canvasPalette(Qt::black);
canvasPalette.setColor(QPalette::Foreground, QColor(133, 190, 232));
canvas()->setPalette(canvasPalette);
}
```

The error is that :

```
'class QWidget' has no member named 'setLineWidth'
'class QWidget' has no member named 'setFrameStyle'
'class QWidget' has no member named 'setBorderRadius'
```

The code is going on,.I mentioned above where the problem is. I tried to solve it myself, but I couldn't figure it out why the problem is caused.

If there is any suggestions, I'll be glad to know that.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You mentionned where was de problem but not which it is. Can you post the error ?

Comment: So, you have an issue, presumably a compilation error, but exactly what? Is it, like, "canvas has not been declared"?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: Oh, that one's easy: (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget-members.html) lists all members, and there really is no `setLineWidth`, for example. Apparently you have the wrong type for `canvas`.

Comment: I understand, so I should find another way to build it, or use another parameter. Thanks a lot, have a nice day.. @Cheersandhth.-Alf .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is a subclass of QwtPlot, so canvas() is QwtPlot::canvas(), which returns a QWidget*, pointing to the member canvas. According to the docs, the default canvas is a QwtPlotCanvas.

You can cast from the returned QWidget* to QwtPlotCanvas, but you should check that the type is correct:

```
QwtPlotCanvas * my_canvas = dynamic_cast<QwtPlotCanvas *>(canvas());
if(my_canvas)
{
  my_canvas->setLineWidth(3); 
  // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem and also thank you for this way, I'll use this if I face the similar situation.